# cifs - file managers upload slower than rsync

Tags: performance, rsync, filemanager, cifs

I'm mounting folders from my NAS on my computer (Ubuntu 18.04) with cifs.
Copying an 8 GB file...

Upload (local -> mounted)

- Nautilus/Nemo -> **6 MB/s**
- rsync -> **50-60 MB/s**

Download performance is also strange, but not my biggest concern.

Download (mounted -> local)

- Nautilus/Nemo -> 90 MB/s
- rsync -> 50-60 MB/s

rsync command (upload):
`rsync --progress /home/me/file.iso /mnt/cifs_media/`

fstab entry:
`//nas/media /mnt/cifs_media cifs vers=3.0,uid=me,gid=me,credentials=/home/me/.smbcredentials,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700 0 0`

Any idea, why the file managers are uploading **up to 10 times more slowly** than rsync, although both using the same cifs, os, hardware, network etc.?